# Creating a text adventure in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java.util.scanner, key-events

I am trying to create a text based adventure in Java I need help in combining a Scanner with JPanel so that the user can type into the panel directly rather than choosing from a list of options. Is there any way of doing this or would a dialogue be needed and if so is there a way of doing so within the JPanel?

Comment: [Text Adventure](https://gist.github.com/okthisisgettingridic/a173b3a9dd0a446aa6ec) on GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing so, you need to add some components to your panel, such as, [JtextField or JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html).

Then you have to add a action listener to your text field/area.

You can find a lot of advices with a simple google search.